# Manipular autocomplete Jquery ui

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar

Estou implementando em um sistema a consulta através de um input utilizando o Autocomplete do Jquery UI.
Na prática ao consultar um valor pelo campo nome(Ex: São) o meu input exibirá uma lista com os possíveis retornos(São Paulo, São Bernardo...).
Esse resultado já possível no meu script, porém eu preciso manipular o Id da cidade selecionada. Sendo que o nome servirá apenas para visualização/seleção do usuário.

Tenho um arquivo php que retorna o Json com as seguintes colunas da tabela, `id`e `nome`.

Já no meu script Jquery eu tenho uma variável do tipo `array` na qual eu armazeno os dados da consulta. Creio que meu problema está aqui, pois não estou sabendo armazenar de uma forma que eu consiga pegar o `id`.

```
    $.getJSON('<?=URL;?>/return-city', function(data){
        var arr = []; 

        // Armazena no array
        $(data).each(function(key, value) {             
            arr.push(value.nome); //Guardo apenas o nome, 
           //porém preciso passar o id para posterior resgate
        });
        console.log(arr);

        $('#location').autocomplete({ source: arr, minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
        var retorno = ui.item.value;
        console.log(retorno); 
        },

        });
    });
```

Este é o retorno do meu Json

```
[Object { nome="Acrelandia",  uf="AC",  id="0001"}, Object { nome="Assis Brasil",  uf="AC",  id="0002"}
```

No evento `select` eu preciso saber como manipular qualquer valor do array seja o nome ou id.

Comment: Ola, para o que percebi com o nome está tudo a correr bem. Agora pretende ter possibilidade de manipular os ids?

Comment: Sim, consigo manipular o `nome ` no evento `SELECT` pois ele que seleciono na lista. Porém o nome só serve para o usuário selecionar a cidade. Em background ao selecionar uma cidade pelo campo `nome ` eu preciso manipular o `id` da mesma para inserir num banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe a possibilidade de passar a informação em JSON dentro do array.

No seu caso deve alterar de.:

```
arr.push(value.nome);
```

Para

```
 arr.push({label:value.nome, value:value.id});
```

Assim quando estão a escrever vai aparecer o nome mas ao selecionar fica o id.
Exemplo no jsfiddle sem ajax.: http://jsfiddle.net/q6jGr/193/

Comment: Sua resposta foi importante para meu entendimento quanto a manipulação do JSON no Autocomplete. No meu caso eu precisava que no input exibisse o nome, mas o evento `select` deveria ouvir o id. Então implementei para `arr.push({label:value.nome, id:value.id})` e no parâmetro capturei o `id` definindo: `ui.item.id;`